# Access to raw disk device in Docker container on Mac

Tags: docker, disk

Is there a way to access to raw disk device in Docker container on Mac?

I would like to mount ext4 filesystem in docker container and edit contents with linux(not mac) tools. I tried `ex4fuse` but it stalls on write operation, reads always fine.

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu 18LTS running on a lenovo SE350,
the following command worked like a charm for me:

```sh
docker run --rm -it --privileged --device=/dev/sda:/dev/sda  gdisk:latest bash
```

I believe this did the magic

```
--privileged --device=/dev/sda:/dev/sda
```

Comment: I think the questions is asking for a way to access a drive directly on a Docker image but with a macOS host system. I don't know if this will work on macOS but, as you're using a Lenovo, I don't think you can guarantee it will work on macOS

Comment: Tried `--device=/dev/disk2s2:/dev/sdc` on Mac, it gives "docker: Error response from daemon: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/dev/disk2s2": not a device node".

Answer (score 1):

In short, it doesn't seem that there is a straightforward and elegant way of using Docker to access an ext4 volume on a macOS host without using FUSE or full virtualisation.

This topic has been covered in further detail on the [DevOps StackExchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4572/how-to-pass-a-dev-disk-device-on-macos-into-linux-docker/5836#5836?newreg=2098155832e7416fa9c1f16a150946ff)